# Deserialize a json response form a Webhook using .net and C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have been trying to understand just how deseriliazion works but have not been successful. I have tried many of the examples but cannot figure out how to deserialize the code below. It's a json response form a Webhook. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[
  {
    "msys": {
      "message_event": {
        "type": "bounce",
        "bounce_class": "1",
        "campaign_id": "Example Campaign Name",
        "customer_id": "1",
        "delv_method": "esmtp",
        "device_token": "45c19189783f867973f6e6a5cca60061ffe4fa77c547150563a1192fa9847f8a",
        "error_code": "554",
        "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
        "message_id": "0e0d94b7-9085-4e3c-ab30-e3f2cd9c273e",
        "msg_from": "sender@example.com",
        "msg_size": "1337",
        "num_retries": "2",
        "rcpt_meta": {
          "customKey": "customValue"
        },
        "rcpt_tags": [
          "male",
          "US"
        ],
        "rcpt_to": "recipient@example.com",
        "rcpt_type": "cc",
        "raw_reason": "MAIL REFUSED - IP (17.99.99.99) is in black list",
        "reason": "MAIL REFUSED - IP (a.b.c.d) is in black list",
        "routing_domain": "example.com",
        "subject": "Summer deals are here!",
        "template_id": "templ-1234",
        "template_version": "1",
        "timestamp": 1427736822,
        "transmission_id": "65832150921904138"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "msys": {
      "message_event": {
        "type": "spam_complaint",
        "campaign_id": "Example Campaign Name",
        "customer_id": "1",
        "delv_method": "esmtp",
        "fbtype": "abuse",
        "friendly_from": "sender@example.com",
        "message_id": "0e0d94b7-9085-4e3c-ab30-e3f2cd9c273e",
        "rcpt_meta": {
          "customKey": "customValue"
        },
        "rcpt_tags": [
          "male",
          "US"
        ],
        "rcpt_to": "recipient@example.com",
        "rcpt_type": "cc",
        "report_by": "server.email.com",
        "report_to": "abuse.example.com",
        "subject": "Summer deals are here!",
        "template_id": "templ-1234",
        "template_version": "1",
        "timestamp": 1427736822,
        "transmission_id": "65832150921904138",
        "user_str": "Additional Example Information"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "msys": {
      "message_event": {
        "type": "out_of_band",
        "bounce_class": "1",
        "campaign_id": "Example Campaign Name",
        "customer_id": "1",
        "delv_method": "esmtp",
        "device_token": "45c19189783f867973f6e6a5cca60061ffe4fa77c547150563a1192fa9847f8a",
        "error_code": "554",
        "message_id": "0e0d94b7-9085-4e3c-ab30-e3f2cd9c273e",
        "msg_from": "sender@example.com",
        "rcpt_to": "recipient@example.com",
        "raw_reason": "MAIL REFUSED - IP (17.99.99.99) is in black list",
        "reason": "MAIL REFUSED - IP (a.b.c.d) is in black list",
        "routing_domain": "example.com",
        "template_id": "templ-1234",
        "template_version": "1",
        "timestamp": 1427736822
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "msys": {
      "track_event": {
        "type": "click",
        "campaign_id": "Example Campaign Name",
        "customer_id": "1",
        "delv_method": "esmtp",
        "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
        "message_id": "0e0d94b7-9085-4e3c-ab30-e3f2cd9c273e",
        "rcpt_meta": {
          "customKey": "customValue"
        },
        "rcpt_tags": [
          "male",
          "US"
        ],
        "rcpt_to": "recipient@example.com",
        "rcpt_type": "cc",
        "target_link_name": "Example Link Name",
        "target_link_url": "http://example.com",
        "template_id": "templ-1234",
        "template_version": "1",
        "timestamp": 1427736822,
        "transmission_id": "65832150921904138",
        "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36",
        "geo_ip": {
          "country": "US",
          "region": "MD",
          "city": "Columbia",
          "latitude": "39.1749",
          "longitude": "-76.8375"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "msys": {
      "track_event": {
        "type": "open",
        "campaign_id": "Example Campaign Name",
        "customer_id": "1",
        "delv_method": "esmtp",
        "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
        "message_id": "0e0d94b7-9085-4e3c-ab30-e3f2cd9c273e",
        "rcpt_meta": {
          "customKey": "customValue"
        },
        "rcpt_tags": [
          "male",
          "US"
        ],
        "rcpt_to": "recipient@example.com",
        "rcpt_type": "cc",
        "template_id": "templ-1234",
        "template_version": "1",
        "timestamp": 1427736822,
        "transmission_id": "65832150921904138",
        "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36",
        "geo_ip": {
          "country": "US",
          "region": "MD",
          "city": "Columbia",
          "latitude": "39.1749",
          "longitude": "-76.8375"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "msys": {
      "unsubscribe_event": {
        "type": "link_unsubscribe",
        "campaign_id": "Example Campaign Name",
        "customer_id": "1",
        "mailfrom": "recipient@example.com",
        "message_id": "0e0d94b7-9085-4e3c-ab30-e3f2cd9c273e",
        "rcpt_meta": {
          "customKey": "customValue"
        },
        "rcpt_tags": [
          "male",
          "US"
        ],
        "rcpt_to": "recipient@example.com",
        "rcpt_type": "cc",
        "template_id": "templ-1234",
        "template_version": "1",
        "timestamp": 1427736822,
        "transmission_id": "65832150921904138",
        "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

My Code:

```
Message_Event jsonarrayMessage_Event = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message_Event>(webhookdata); 
campaign_id = jsonarrayMessage_Event.campaign_id.ToString(); 
rcpt_to = jsonarrayMessage_Event.rcpt_to.ToString(); 
subject = jsonarrayMessage_Event.subject.ToString();
```

But I keep getting the error:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Message_Event' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Comment: It would be easier to build on your code if you post what you have tried so far.

Comment: My code is: 

webhookdata = TextBox1.Text.ToString().Trim(); Message_Event jsonarrayMessage_Event = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message_Event>(webhookdata); campaign_id = jsonarrayMessage_Event.campaign_id.ToString(); rcpt_to = jsonarrayMessage_Event.rcpt_to.ToString(); subject = jsonarrayMessage_Event.subject.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a class to hold the data

```
public class MessageEvent 
{
    public string type{ get; set; }
    public int bounce_class { get; set; }
    ... etc 
}
```

and then use the following to deserialize it.

```
MessageEvent tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageEvent>(json);
```

Edit: As Volkan says you'll need an external library for to use JsonConvert. You can find it on NuGet - search for Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: In case OP is not familiar, this solution requires an external library called Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: My code is:
webhookdata = TextBox1.Text.ToString().Trim();    
 Message_Event jsonarrayMessage_Event = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message_Event>(webhookdata);
campaign_id = jsonarrayMessage_Event.campaign_id.ToString();
 rcpt_to = jsonarrayMessage_Event.rcpt_to.ToString();
 subject = jsonarrayMessage_Event.subject.ToString();

Comment: Error:
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Message_Event' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array.

Comment: Change Message_Event jsonarrayMessage_Event = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message_Event>(webhookdata);  to List<Message_Event> jsonarrayMessage_Event

Answer (score 0):

You can use newtonsoft json.net nugget - build a data model accordingly to you json and use that model as documented here :

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm

Nugget Gallery

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

You can also use the visual studio cool feature : Copy json to your clipboard (Ctrl + C) and then past it as C# class...

Edit -> Past Special -> Paste Json As Classes

This is very convenient way to deal with complex json objects

Answer (score 0):

My code is:

```
webhookdata = TextBox1.Text.ToString().Trim(); 

Message_Event jsonarrayMessage_Event = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message_Event>(webhookdata); 
campaign_id = jsonarrayMessage_Event.campaign_id.ToString(); 
rcpt_to = jsonarrayMessage_Event.rcpt_to.ToString(); 
subject = jsonarrayMessage_Event.subject.ToString();
```

Error I get is:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Message_Event' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.